# How to show that $f(x_1,x_3)=f(x_1,x_2)f(x_2,x_3)\implies f(x,y)=g(x)/g(y)$

Tags: functions

I wanted to know if there was a nice way of showing that $f(x_1,x_3)=f(x_1,x_2)f(x_2,x_3)\forall x_1,x_2,x_3\implies f(x,y)=g(x)/g(y)$ for some function $g$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write the equation with $x_3$ changed to $1$ and divide the given equation by the new one. You get $\frac {f(x_1,x_3)} {f(x_1,1)}=\frac {f(x_2,x_3)} {f(x_2,1)}$. What this equation tells you is that the function $\frac {f(x,x_3)} {f(x,1)}$ has the same value at any two points $x=x_1$ and $x=x_2$. Hence it is independent of $x$. Call it $h(x_3)$. We get $f(x,y)=h(y)f(x,1)$. Can you complete the argument now? [You will need the fact $f(x,x)=f(x,x)^{2}$ so $f(x,x) =1$ (assuming $f(x,x) \neq 0$. Note the result does not make sense for $f \equiv 0$ so we have to make some assumptions about zeros of $f$)].  More details: you get $1=h(x)f(x,1)$ by putting $y=x$. I claim that the conclusion holds with $g =\frac 1 h$. We have to show $f(x,y)=\frac {g(x)} {g(y}$ which is same as $f(x,y)=\frac {h(y)} {h(x)}$. By $f(x,y)=h(y)f(x,1)$ this becomes $h(y)f(x,1)=\frac {h(y)} {h(x)}$. This is true because $h(x)f(x,1)=1$.

Comment: Sorry but do you mind pushing it all the way?

Comment: @AakashLakshmanan I have given a detailed proof now.